# Makie: Non-overlapping label placement algorithm for scatter plots

Tags: julia, scatter-plot, makie.jl

I am using CairoMakie to scatter plot an XY data set but using labels as markers:

```
using CairoMakie


x = [0, 0.5, 0.50]
y = [0, 0.5, 0.51]
lbls = ["O", "A", "B"]

fig = Figure()
ax = Axis(fig[1,1])
scatter!(ax, x, y, marker=:circle, markersize=10, color=:red)
foreach(i -> text!(ax, position=(x[i], y[i]), lbls[i]), 1:3)

display(fig)
```

This produces the following figure:

[image: XY scatter with text labels]

Because points `A` and `B` are very close with each other, their respective labels overlap. Does CairoMakie have an algorithm to place the labels in such a way to avoid label overlaps?

I know Gadfly has this capability with `Geom.label` but I am hoping I do not have to use a separate package just to plot such charts. I also know in CairoMakie, I can use arguments such as `position` and `offset` to adjust the label positioning in such a way the labels do not overlap, but I cannot do this for every data set in my case.

Can anyone help? Or perhaps have a label placement algorithm written in Julia? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is amazing that several math papers have been written on non-overlapping label placement algorithms, but I neither have the math background nor the time to study these papers, let alone translate the algorithm into code. Python and R have codes for this kind of algorithm.

Anyway, the following code in Julia is sufficient for my case, not necessarily holistic enough for all situations and for everyone's case.

```
using DataFrames
using CairoMakie
using Random


function allpairs(n::Int)
    arr = collect(Iterators.product(1:n, 1:n))
    row, col = size(arr)
    combo = []
    for r ∈ 1:row-1, c ∈ (r + 1):col
        push!(combo, arr[r, c])
    end
    combo
end


angle(x, y) = atan(y[2] - y[1], x[2] - x[1])


dist(x, y) = sqrt((x[2] - x[1])^2 + (y[2] - y[1])^2)


function label_dist(x, y, δw, δh)
    x1, x2 = x[1], x[2]
    y1, y2 = y[1], y[2]
    x1b, x2b = x1 + δw, x2 + δw
    y1b, y2b = y1 + δh, y2 + δh

    left = x2b < x1
    right = x1b < x2
    bottom = y2b < y1
    top = y1b < y2

    d = top && left ? dist((x1, x2b), (y1b, y2)) :
        left && bottom ? dist((x1, x2b), (y1, y2b)) :
        bottom && right ? dist((x1b, x2), (y1, y2b)) :
        right && top ? dist((x1b, x2), (y1b, y2)) :
        left ? x1 - x2b :
        right ? x2 - x1b :
        bottom ? y1 - y2b :
        top ? y2 - y1b :
        0.0
    d
end


function shift!(x, y, idx, r, angle)
    x[idx[1]] -= r * cos(angle)
    y[idx[1]] -= r * sin(angle)
    x[idx[2]] += r * cos(angle)
    y[idx[2]] += r * sin(angle)
end


function label_pos(x, y;               # label positions (original/untransformed scale)
                   min_dist=0.002,     # min. distance between labels (on a 0-1 scale)
                   shift_size=0.002,   # distance to shift labels (on a 0-1 scale)
                   width=0.05,         # width of label (on a 0-1 scale)
                   height=0.03,        # height of label (on a 0-1 scale)
                   attempts::Int=100)  # no. of tries to place labels
    xlims = extrema(x)
    Δx = xlims[2] - xlims[1]
    ylims = extrema(y)
    Δy = ylims[2] - ylims[1]

    xt = (x .- xlims[1]) ./ Δx  # map to a 0-1 scale
    yt = (y .- ylims[1]) ./ Δy

    combo = allpairs(length(xt))
    iter = true
    i = 1
    while iter
        pts = map(combo) do p
            idx = [p[1], p[2]]
            d = label_dist(xt[idx], yt[idx], width, height)
            θ = angle(xt[idx], yt[idx])
            (idx=idx, dist=d, angle=θ)
        end

        pos = findall(p -> p.dist < min_dist, pts)
        foreach(p -> shift!(xt, yt, p.idx, shift_size, p.angle), pts[pos])
        i += 1
        iter = (i <= attempts) && !isempty(pos)
    end

    xt = xt .* Δx .+ xlims[1]   # revert to original scale
    yt = yt .* Δy .+ ylims[1]

    (; x=xt, y=yt)
end


xlims = (0, 1)
ylims = (-10, 10)

Δxl = xlims[2] - xlims[1]
Δyl = ylims[2] - ylims[1]

n = 150      # no. of points to generate
seed = 392348
Random.seed!(seed)
xs = xlims[1] .+ rand(n) .* Δxl
ys = ylims[1] .+ rand(n) .* Δyl

labels = map(i -> "$i", eachindex(xs))

xt = xs[:]
yt = ys[:]
xt2 = xs[:]
yt2 = ys[:]

xt, yt = label_pos(xt, yt)

xlims2 = (xlims[1] - Δxl * 0.05, xlims[2] + Δxl * 0.05)
ylims2 = (ylims[1] - Δyl * 0.05, ylims[2] + Δyl * 0.05)

fig = Figure(resolution=(600,1200))  # must be square and preferably >500 px
axs = Axis(fig[1,1])
scatter!(axs, xs, ys, marker=:circle, markersize=5, color=:red)
axs.title = "non-overlap label placement"

foreach(eachindex(labels)) do i
    text!(axs, position=(xt[i], yt[i]), labels[i], textsize=15, align=(:right, :bottom))
end

axs2 = Axis(fig[2,1])
scatter!(axs2, xs, ys, marker=:circle, markersize=5, color=:red)
axs2.title = "default label placement"

limits!(axs, xlims2, ylims2)
limits!(axs2, xlims2, ylims2)

foreach(eachindex(labels)) do i
    text!(axs2, position=(xt2[i], yt2[i]), labels[i], textsize=15, align=(:right, :bottom))
end

display(fig)
```

The code produces the following 2 charts:

[image]

It is hardly near perfect or optimized, but it teases apart the labels far enough, so that I can save the figures as SVG, then use a vector drawing app to manually adjust the labels, where needed.

This is a start, as I am sure cleverer people can optimize this code. I hope this will be helpful to others.

Comment: Update: This is a better version: https://gist.github.com/cbsteh/a00ba6cd5752d38f962168523a9f6898

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the label letters O, A, B individually, I would consider having custom offsets as well:

```
using CairoMakie


x = [0, 0.5, 0.50]
y = [0, 0.5, 0.51]
lbls = ["O", "A", "B"]
xoffset = [0, -0.015, 0.005]
yoffset = [0, -0.02, 0]

fig = Figure()
ax = Axis(fig[1,1])
scatter!(ax, x, y, marker=:circle, markersize=10, color=:red)
foreach(i -> text!(ax, position=(x[i] + xoffset[i], y[i] + yoffset[i]), lbls[i]), 1:3)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am trying to avoid manually adjusting each point, as I have many data sets to plot.

Answer (score 0):

I've just wrote a paper about label placement algorithms. There exists many algorithms out there for different use cases. This paper here (not mine, haha) introduces a novel approach which could be fit to your use case:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/10017860

Basically its a greedy algorithm. You define three forces

1. An attractive force, to keep the label nearby its correspoding point
2. An repulsive force to keep the label away from other labels
3. An repulsive force to keep the label away from points that does correspont to another label

Then you sum up the forces and add them with some delta to your label position. You do this until you hit a termination condition (e.g. summed up force hits a minimum or running time/iterations hits a maximum)