# How to add text labels to a scatterplot?

Tags: plot, julia

Is there a way to add text labels to the points on a scatterplot? Each point has a string associated with it as its label. I like to label only as many points as it can be done withour overlapping?

```
df = DataFrame(x=rand(100), y=rand(100), z=randstring.(fill(5,100)))
scatter(df.x, df.y)
annotate!(df.x, df.y, text.(df.z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `StatisticalGraphics` package:

```
using InMemoryDatasets
using StatisticalGraphics
using Random

ds=Dataset(x=rand(100), y=rand(100), z=randstring.(fill(5,100)))
sgplot(ds, Scatter(x=:x,y=:y,labelresponse=:z))
```

[image]

Comment: if there is another column `insertcols!(ds,:g=>rand(["g1","g2"],100))`, then it is possible to code like `sgplot(ds, Scatter(x=:x,y=:y,group=:g,labelresponse=:z,labelcolor=:group))`, fascinating!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I wrote for `Makie.jl` that suited my needs:

[Non-overlapping labels for scatter plots](https://gist.github.com/cbsteh/a00ba6cd5752d38f962168523a9f6898)

It works best for single line, short text labels, and where all labels have similar lengths with one another. It is still WIP, as I am working to improve it for placement of longer text labels.

Here are some samples of what it can do:

[image: Near linear distribution of data]
[image: Random distribution of data]
[image: Quadratic distribution of data]

Essentially, you call function `viz` to plot a scatter chart on your `(x, y)` data set:

```
resolution = (600, 600)     # figure size (pixels) -- need not be a equal dimension
fontpt = 12                 # label font size (points)
flabel = 1.5                # inflate the label size to create some margins
fdist = 0.3                 # inflate the max. distance between a label and its
                            #   anchor point before a line is drawn to connect. them.
                            #   Smaller values would create more connecting lines.

viz(x, y, labels; resolution=resolution, flabel=flabel, fdist=fdist, fontpt=fontpt)
```

where `labels` is a list containing the text labels for every pair of `(x, y)` point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extra named argument `series_annotations` in the scatter function. Here us an example where I use "1", "2", etc. as labels:

```
using Plots

x = collect(0:0.1:2)
y = sinpi.(x)

scatter(x, y, series_annotations = text.(1:length(x), :top))
```

[image]

Avoiding overlaps is more difficult.  You could customize your label with empty "" for duplicates where the points are the same, or see for Makie: [Makie: Non-overlapping label placement algorithm for scatter plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73976927/makie-non-overlapping-label-placement-algorithm-for-scatter-plots)